# Intellisense does not work

Tags: sql-server, intellisense, ssms-2014

I recently installed MS SQL Server Mgmt. Studio 2014 and discovered Intellisense was not working at all even though it was enabled by default.

What's interesting is that the icon on the toolbar to disable/enable Intellisense is grayed out so that I can't enable or disable it.

I've done a fair amount of searching but haven't found an answer or even probable cause.

I tried using the hotkey combo, Ctrl+Q followed by Ctrl+I but I get the following message in the status bar of SSMS:

"The key combination (Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+I) is bound to command (IntelliSense Enabled) which is not currently available."

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you ever tried refreshing local cache ( Ctrl + Shift + R)?  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173434%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: @OscarSan - Yes, I have tried that and checked all the settings as well.

Comment: What is the version of SQL Sever you are connecting to?

Comment: Further to SQLChao's comment, Intellisense will only work if you are connected a SQL Server that is 2008 or higher, regardless of what version of SSMS you are using.

Comment: @SQLChao - Looks like it is SQL Server 9.0.5324

Comment: @DeanOC -  ahhhh...that makes sense.  I guess our SQL server needs to be upgraded.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are connected to SQL Server 9.0.5324, which is SQL Server 2005, and Intellisense wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2008.

You can connect to older versions of SQL Server with SSMS 2014, but Intellisense will only work when you connect to a server that is 2008 or newer.

No way around this I'm afraid.

Comment: Goofy that something like parenthesis matching doesn't work in such a case.